# Tensorflow returns same accuracy regardless of number of steps in classifier.fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Changing the steps from 2000 to 1 in the `classifier.fit` function returns the same accuracy results. I would expect the accuracy results to be different, can someone tell me why?

Code is from Tensorflow example :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "iris_training.csv")
IRIS_TEST = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "iris_test.csv")

def main(unused_argv):
    # Load datasets.
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
        filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int, features_dtype=np.float32)

    test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
        filename=IRIS_TEST, target_dtype=np.int, features_dtype=np.float32)

    # Specify that all features have real-value data
    feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]

    # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
    classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                                hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                                n_classes=3,
                                                model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")

    # Fit model.
    classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
                   y=training_set.target,
                   steps=1)

    # Evaluate accuracy.
    accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=test_set.data,
                                         y=test_set.target)["accuracy"]
    print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))

    # Classify two new flower samples.
    new_samples = np.array(
        [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]], dtype=float)
    y = list(classifier.predict(new_samples, as_iterable=True))
    print('Predictions: {}'.format(str(y)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: I've just run this example and it worked normal. Accuracy with step 2000 is 0.96666664.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is very simple: you have defined `model_dir` argument of your classifier. Here's what the doc says:

> `model_dir`: Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. This can
>   also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator
>   to continue training a previously saved model.

When you run your model several times, it doesn't learn from the scratch, but picks up previous weights from `"/tmp/iris_model"`.

If you want to do a fair test, remove this argument and you'll see how accuracy drops for small steps and goes high for high steps.